# What's the best way to document intentional switch fall-through?

Tags: php, switch-statement, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have found myself in a situation where a switch case fall-through is the best option. By this I mean:

```
switch($bar)
{
    case 0:
        // do something
    case 1:
        // do more
        break;
    //more cases
}
```

Currently my IDE (phpStorm) is throwing a warning about the fall-through.

**Is there an accepted way in phpDoc to document such intended fall-through?**

n.b. I'm aware that some of you will undoubtedly say not to do this but I subscribe to this [definition of evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/defn-evil.html) and this is certainly the 'the least bad of the alternatives'.

Comment: I always put `// Deliberate fallthrough` in a comment to the right of the colon, though this is more for the programmer's sake. I don't think you can disable the warning for the IDE

Comment: the only way to get rid of the warning would be to configure the warnings, that phpstorm prints, in this case remove the warning of fall-throughs. but that is not really productive because maybe in another script you just forget the break and therefore the warning would be of use. i handle it by just ignoring the warning and maybe add an extra comment or something comparable to it to make clear this was intentionally written as it is.

Comment: @GordonM I do this already but just wondered if there was a more formal way of documenting this behavior.

Comment: As the other commenter said, the only way is to turn the warning off (I'm not highly familiar with PHPStorm, so I'll take their word for it).  Given that cases where you accidentally fall through are potentially far more serious than cases where you get warned about a deliberate fall through, and given how deliberately falling through isn't something you should be doing very often anyway, I'd just live with the warnings.

Comment: There is no phpDocumentor tag for indicating such behavior.

Comment: @luk2302 your comment is not longer (I can't test if it was ever correct) correct. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Although the question explicitly asks about phpDoc, here's an IDE-specific solution for PHPStorm.

For Javascript, comment

```
//noinspection FallthroughInSwitchStatementJS
```

above the switch statement.

For PHP, comment

```
/** @noinspection PhpMissingBreakStatementInspection */
```

above the offending case statement.

Comment: Lovely! That's the sort of thing I was hoping for. Thanks.

Comment: In PHPStorm (probably in other JetBrains IDEs too), you can also press Alt+Enter with the cursor over the offending piece of code and select "Suppress for statement". Then the appropriate comment to disable the inspection will be automagically inserted at the right position.

Comment: This does help, but it would still be nice if PhpDoc could have a tag like @fallthrough :) Maybe something for PHP-Fig

Comment: In JavaScript, `/** @noinspection FallthroughInSwitchStatementJS */` or even just `/** @noinspection Fallthrough */` is working for me as well (WebStorm 10).

Comment: @donquixote The PhpDocumentor team has stated they intend to stick to the minimum tags necessary for generating *external documentation.* While some class/method tags are up for debate, they definitely will not support adding tags inside functions.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Thanks. This is is understandable from a PhpDocumentor point of view. Which means the place would be the php-fig. Or maybe we need a new forum for a continuous, cross-framework and cross-IDE discussion about new doc comment syntax, that is more focused on code vs IDE, than about generating external documentation.

Comment: This solution sounds doable for PHPStorm users, but it doesn't quite conform with the PSR standards. There they mandate a comment `// no break` or something similar... And I would expect Storm to catch that instead of require me to add an ugly, private `@noinspection` flag to my code :/